If God YHWH is “the Angel of the LORD” in the form of pre-incarnate Jesus in the OT, why does He not “rebuke” Satan Himself? (Zechariah 3:2)
Some Protestants and Catholics believe “the Angel of the LORD” frequently mentioned in the OT, to be God YHWH himself in the form of pre-incarnate Jesus. They use the unbiblical term of “theophany” for this:

It seems when the definite article “the” is used, it is specifying a unique being, separate from the other angels. The angel of the Lord speaks as God, identifies Himself with God, and exercises the responsibilities of God (Genesis 16:7-12; 21:17-18; 22:11-18; Exodus 3:2; Judges 2:1-4; 5:23; 6:11-24; 13:3-22; 2 Samuel 24:16; Zechariah 1:12; 3:1; 12:8). In several of these appearances, those who saw the angel of the Lord feared for their lives because they had “seen the Lord.” Therefore, it is clear that in at least some instances, the angel of the Lord is a theophany, an appearance of God in physical form….whether the angel of the Lord was a pre-incarnate appearance of Christ (Christophany) or an appearance of God the Father (theophany), it is highly likely that the phrase “the angel of the Lord” usually identifies a physical appearance of God. (Protestant apologetics site GotQuestions.org)

A Catholic “Dictionary” describes the term “theophany” like this:

A direct communication or appearance by God to human beings. Instances: God confronting Adam and Eve after their disobedience (Genesis 3:8); God appearing to Moses out of a burning bush (Exodus 3:2-6); Abraham pleading with Yahweh to be merciful to Sodomites (Genesis 18:23). These theophanies were temporary manifestations. They were not like the Incarnation, which, though it began in time, will continue for all eternity.

One such “theophany” in the form of “the angel of the Lord” is found in Zechariah:

Then he showed me Joshua the high priest standing before the Angel of the LORD, and Satan standing at his right hand to oppose him. (Zechariah 3:1 - NKJV)

Protestant and Catholic scholars agree that this account describes a Theophany - God appears in the second person of the Trinity (Jesus) as the Angel of the Lord.

This angel was Christ, or the Logos, mentioned Zechariah 1:11, and called the Lord in the following verse (Benson Commentary)


standing before the Angel of the Lord; not any created angel, but Christ the Angel of God's presence, who is called Jehovah, Zechariah 3:2 is the rebuker of Satan, and the advocate of his people; (Gill’s Exposition of the Entire Bible)

Interesting with this account is the following utterance by this “angel of the LORD” in Zechariah 3:2

And the LORD [the Angel of the LORD speaking as the LORD] said to Satan, “The LORD rebuke you, Satan! The LORD who has chosen Jerusalem rebuke you! Is this not a brand plucked from the fire (Zechariah 3:2 NKJV)

Why does GOD in the form of the second person of the Trinity, manifesting Himself as the Angel of the LORD not rebuke Satan, but asks YHWH (the LORD) to do so?
The exact same words “The LORD rebuke you” are spoken by the Archangel Michael in Jude 9 over the body of Moses when it says:

Yet Michael the archangel, in contending with the devil, when he disputed about the body of Moses, dared not bring against him a reviling accusation, but said, “The Lord rebuke you“ (Jude 9 NKJV)

Could it be that the Angel of the LORD similarly “dared not bring against him (Satan) a reviling accusation” in Zechariah 3:2? If so, how could He be GOD?
What other reason could there be NOT to rebuke Satan?
One possible answer is found in 2 Peter 2:11

whereas angels, who are greater in power and might [than humans], do not bring a reviling accusation against them before the Lord.

This would suggest that the Angel of the Lord does have the same level of authority granted by GOD YHWH than many other Angels. It would mean that “the Angel of the LORD” is neither God nor the second person of the Trinity.
How do those that hold to the position of “the Angel of the Lord” in Zechariah 3:1-2 being Christ pre-incarnate/God reconcile this? Why does the AOTL not rebuke Satan but asks YHWH/the LORD to do so?

"pre-incarnate" is unbiblical as well

Related. https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/18541/23657

There is clearly a relationship expressed in the hints of revelation given regarding Deity in ancient times.
'The Lord said to my Lord - Sit thou,' is spoken from One to Another, an order of relationship : 'My Father is greater than I'.
'God, thy God hath anointed thee with the oil of gladness above thy fellows' also conveys a relationship and an exaltation within order.
David was conscious of this relationship : 'The Lord' and 'my Lord'.
And that One saith 'The Lord rebuke thee, O Satan' speaks of not only a filial regard to One greater in relationship (Father) but also speaks of One aware that he has not yet gained ascendancy over the created Arche.
Not, that is, until he is manifested, until he suffers, until all righteousness is fulfilled, until death is overcome : until the promised one from above bruises the head of the Serpent.
It indicates not only filial regard to One greater (by Fatherhood) it also speaks of subjection to created order and that righteous activity is needed before he takes the place already chosen for him by God and the Father.
It is a more fulsome revelation than a mere hint of plurality of Deity : it is a revelation of relationship within that Deity.

I agree with most of what you’ve written - from a Trinitarian perspective (how I understand it), I’m confused; I thought Christ was only subordinate to the Father in his humanity and not eternally. If Jesus/God was the creator, how could He not have “ascendancy” over His creation? How can even an economic subordination be denoting eternal co-equality? The bible talks about husband and wife becoming one flesh - it’s an economic relationship - but the husband is still the head - they are not co-equal! The head of Christ is God… it also looks like an ontological subordination in both cases.

@JsWitness "I thought Christ was only subordinate to the Father in his humanity and not eternally.".  Not so.  The Word/Logos/Christ, who was with God and was God in the beginning, always and only accomplishes the Father's will.  God ontologically and subordinate relationally.

@MikeBorden - it is obvious from Zachariah that the Angel of the Lord (who as some believe is the Lord YHWH) wants Satan to be rebuked. If three persons are fully unified in their will, the YHWH the Father wants it too - so why does YHWH the Son (the AotL) not do it? Why does He not have the authority to do YHWHs will? Unless, he is NOT YHWH, this doesn’t make any sense!

There is another possibility which the text allows.

And he sheweth me Joshua the high priest standing before the messenger of Jehovah, and the Adversary standing at his right hand, to be an adversary to him. And Jehovah saith unto the Adversary: 'Jehovah doth push against thee, O Adversary, Yea, push against thee doth Jehovah, Who is fixing on Jerusalem, Is not this a brand delivered from fire?' - Zechariah 3:1-2 Young's Literal Translation

This translation has Jehovah speaking to Satan, whether directly or through the messenger/angel and what is said is not a request for rebuking but, rather, a statement of it.
There are a few translations which render the passage similarly:
"And the LORD said to the Adversary: "The LORD rebukes you, Adversary. The LORD, the one choosing Jerusalem, rebukes you. Is this one not a log snatched from the fire?" - CEB
"But Yahweh said to Satan, "Yahweh rebukes you, O Satan! Yahweh who has chosen Jerusalem rebukes you! [Is] this not a stick snatched from the fire?" - LEB
The similar usage in Jude is in the aorist tense, which is silent about when the action takes place, and so can easily be understood as a statement of He has, He is, or He will.  It can also be understood as a statement of fact rather than a request.  Much like saying, "The Lord judge between me and thee."
The same word is used 14 times in the Masoretic Text: "Corrupt" -  Malachi 2:3. "Rebuke" - Ruth 2:16, Psalm 68:30, Isaiah 17:13 and 54:9, Malachi 3:11.  "Rebuked" - Genesis 37:10, Psalms 9:5, 106:9, 199:21.  "Reproved" - Jeremiah 29:27.  In Nahum 1:4 it is usually rendered "rebukes" rather than "rebuke":

He rebuketh the sea, and maketh it dry, and drieth up all the rivers: Bashan languisheth, and Carmel, and the flower of Lebanon languisheth.

This exact same word is used as past, present, and future tense; as request and as statement.  In summary, there is nothing conclusive in the Hebrew text to relegate "The Lord rebuke you" to a request rather than a statement of fact.
If it is a statement of fact, as Young's Literal translates and the text allows, the Angel of the Lord in this passage could be a 'mere angel' or a Christophany.  This doesn't answer the question of who the Angel of the Lord may be here or in any given passage but, then again, that was not the question.

This is an interesting interpretative possibility. However, even if it is a statement, which according to Jude was made because the angel "dared not bring against him a reviling accusation", it does not explain why the Angel of YHWH would not say "I rebuke you" if He is YHWH in the form of Christ. So the question might also be: is the Angel of Lord speaking in Zechariah 3:2 Christ?
